# how to write a recursive function that would return the minimum values in a BST?

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a recursive fucntion that will return the 
minimum value in a binary search tree.

```
int RecursiveFindMin(Tree t) {
  if (t==NULL)
    return -1;
  else {
    if (t!=NULL)
        RecursiveFindMin(t->left);
  }

  return t->val;   
}
```

I expect to get the minimum value in the BST

Instead, I am getting the second smallest result, most of the time!
I am not very good at recursive functions and I would appreciate the 
help!

Comment: There is no need in recursion here as the minimum is located in the leftmost leaf and can be found by simple iteration. In your function you are discarding the return value of the recursive call.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I imagine the assignment asks them to use recursion

Comment: @HunterMcMillen that's right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make recursive calls to your function, you discard the return value.  So the recursion is effectively doing nothing.  All you're doing is returning the value of the first node passed in.

You're also not using the right exit condition.  You want to stop not when the current node is NULL (because what can you do with it then?) but when the *left* node is NULL.  Then the value you want is in that node.

So change the condition to check the left node, and return the value of the recursive call:

```
int RecursiveFindMin(Tree t) {
  if (t->left==NULL)
    return t->val;   
  else {
    return RecursiveFindMin(t->left);
  }
}
```

Comment: @M.Hamra Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning every left node value. So finally it returns the root value. You should find the leftmost node and fixed that value as the minimum one.

```
const int kInf = 100000000;
int RecursiveFindMin(Tree t) {
    if (t == NULL) return kInf;
    int v = RecursiveFindMin(t->left);
    return v == kInf? t->val : v;   
}
```

I have used `kInf` for a value not present in the tree.

Comment: const int kInf = 100000000;  - How did you choose this constant.? may be 0x7fffffff (considering 4bytes for int)more meaningful ?

Comment: This is just a placeholder value. The value should be any value not in the tree.